# Increment count each time a file is called in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have an upload button whereby the file selected by the user gets uploaded to a specific directory when the user clicks on the upload button. The upload button calls the upload.php file.

I have a page whereby for one question, a maximum of 5 option answer can be filled while creating a quiz as well as upload an audio soundtrack for each of the options entered.

**A snapshot of the page**
[image]

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$count=0;

$count++;

$target_dir = "Uploads/Question".$count."/Options/";
$target_file = "Uploads/Question".$count."/Options/".$count.".mp3"; //renames file as 1, 2, 3 etc.
$uploadOk = 1;
$audioFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<br/>Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
    echo "<br/>Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

//Allow certain file formats
if($audioFileType != "avi" && $audioFileType != "mp3" && $audioFileType != "mp4"
&& $audioFileType != "wma" ) {
    echo "<br/>Only AVI, mp3, mp4 & WMA files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "<br/>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "<br/>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

This part of the code `$target_file = "Uploads/Question".$count."/Options/".$count.".mp3";` is supposed to save the file as 1.mp3 and I want to increment the 1 as 1, 2, 3 etc each time. As you can see the count is set to 0 at the start of the file itself.
My question would be, how can I increment the count each time the upload.php file is called?

It was a bit long as it was difficult to explain. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: You would have to store something in a database or flat file and retrieve the last value before incrementing to the new value.

Comment: From research I've found that the easiest way would be to count the number of files in the directory itself. Any help on that?

Comment: Your code has no way of processing more than 1 uploaded file at a time? Are you asking how do I process more than 1 file being uploaded in one execution???

Comment: No I only wanted to have a way to increment the count of the renamed files each time the upload.php file is called. I found an easy way for that. I'll answer it myself to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to increment the count would be to count the number of files already present in that directory.

**Updated upload.php**

```
<?php
$count=0;

$count++;


$i = 1; 
$dir = "Uploads/Question".$count."/Options/"; //count files in that directory
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
        if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
            $i++;
    }
}

$target_dir = "Uploads/Question".$count."/Options/";
$target_file = "Uploads/Question".$count."/Options/".$i.".mp3"; //renames file as 1, 2, 3 etc.
$uploadOk = 1;
$audioFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<br/>Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
    echo "<br/>Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

//Allow certain file formats
if($audioFileType != "avi" && $audioFileType != "mp3" && $audioFileType != "mp4"
&& $audioFileType != "wma" ) {
    echo "<br/>Only AVI, mp3, mp4 & WMA files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "<br/>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "<br/>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

**The folder:**
[image]